# No suitable method found to override OnModelCreating()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When I try to override `OnModelCreating` virtual function it says no suitable method found to override. I'm pretty sure that I've installed all necessary Entity Framework packages

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MVCOurselves.Models
{
    public class MVCOurselvesContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Grade> Grades { get; set; }

        public MVCOurselvesContext (DbContextOptions<MVCOurselvesContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // configures one-to-many relationship
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasRequired<Grade>(s => s.Grade)
                .WithMany(g => g.Students)
                .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.Id);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If you update from older EF.. just use `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`

Comment: And remove all `using System.Data.Entity;` to avoid unexpected errors by mixing EF6 and EF Core methods with the same name. And before you get the next error, please note that EF Core has different APIs, for instance there is no `HasRequired` / `HasOptional` etc. fluent API for relationships (in EF Core the method is called `HasOne`). There are also many other differences.

Comment: thank you very much for amazing support

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After looking your code it seems that you you have upgraded your application from `ASP.NET MVC` to `ASP.NET Core` but its still referencing ASP.NET MVC libraries.

Remove `using System.Data.Entity` and replace `DbModelBuilder` with `ModelBuilder` and also rewrite the `one-to-many` configuration as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MVCOurselves.Models
{
    public class MVCOurselvesContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Grade> Grades { get; set; }

        public MVCOurselvesContext (DbContextOptions<MVCOurselvesContext> 
options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder 
modelBuilder)
        {
            // configures one-to-many relationship
            modelBuilder.Entity<Grades>()
                        .HasMany(g => g.Students)
                        .WithOne(s => s.Grade)
                        .HasForeignKey(s => s.GradeId);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Great to hear that. Welcome!